# Bundler errors when bundling w/Rails 5.0.6 after upgrading from 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

Trying to upgrade Ruby 2.2/Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0.6 (already gave up on 5.0.7.2 since it seems to require Zeitwerk which requires Ruby >= 2.4.4). The issue is I'm getting error messages about 25 gems from bundler that look similar to this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    premailer-rails was resolved to 1.11.1, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 3)

    rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 5.0.6)
```

Now, I've got `gem "rails", '5.0.6'` in my gem file and no listing for actionmailer. It seems that actionmailer 5.0.6 would satisfy both of those requirements, so why is bundler complaining (I did list actionmailer in the `bundle update` command)? More importantly, what can I do to get past this issue?

On a prior Rails upgrade, I removed the gemfile.lock and did a `bundle install` and did eventually get it working. So I tried that with this upgrade, only to get the same set of errors. I also tried `bundle update --all` and got the same errors.

Here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.10'

gem 'rails', '5.0.6'
gem 'railties', '5.0.6'

gem 'rake', '~> 10.4.2'             # Version added when moving to RSpec 2.99
gem 'rack-cache', '1.5.1'           # Added for 'rake', '~>10.4.2'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.15.0'               # AR on 4.2 requires 0.15
# Note: must edit database.yml to include "host: local" and remove the username put there by "rails new <app> -db postgresql"

gem 'puma', '3.11.4'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'sidekiq', '2.13.1', path: 'vendor/sidekiq/sidekiq-2.13.1'
gem 'sidekiq-pro', '1.2.2', path: 'vendor/sidekiq-pro/sidekiq-pro-1.2.2'
gem 'celluloid', '0.15.2'           # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'redis', '3.3.3'                # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'redis-namespace', '1.5.2'      # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'connection_pool', '2.2.0'      # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13
# Need the following gems for sidekiq/web
gem 'slim'
# if you require 'sinatra' you get the DSL extended to Object
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil

gem 'minitest', '5.9.1'             # Added when moving to Rails 4.1.16
gem 'jeff', '~>1.2'                 # Added when moving to Rails 4.1.16
gem 'excon', '0.22.1'               # Added when moving to Rails 4.1.16
gem 'raindrops', '0.19.1'           # Added when moving to Rails 4.1.16

gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.8'


gem 'a2z', '0.1.2'

gem 'public_suffix', '1.5.3'        # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'hitimes', '1.2.2'              # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'ffi', '1.9.6'                  # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'faraday', '0.8.9'              # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'net-http-persistent', '2.5.2'  # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13

gem 'platform-api', '2.1.0'         # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13

gem 'json', '1.8.6'                 # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13

gem 'lograge'

gem 'oauth2', '0.9.4'
gem 'omniauth', '1.2.1'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '1.1.2'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '0.2.4'    # Google OAuth-2 Login via OmniAuth
gem 'jwt', '1.0.0'                  # Added when moving to Rails 4.0.13

gem 'premailer-rails'     # Converts CSS styles to inline styles, creates plain-text email from HTML email
gem 'premailer', '1.8.4'            # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'psych', '2.0.5'

gem 'stripe', '1.25.0', path: 'vendor/stripe/stripe-ruby-1.25.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'mechanize', '2.7.2'            # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.7.2'           # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'spreadsheet', '> 0.9.0'
gem 'roo', '2.5.1'                  # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'roo-xls'
gem 'xml-simple'
gem 'rubyzip', '1.2.2'              # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
gem 'scbi_multi_gz_reader'

gem 'rmagick', '2.15.4'             # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.0'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'geoip'

gem 'byebug', '~> 10.0.0'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring', '2.0.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'faker', '~> 0.3.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '2.8.0'               # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
  gem 'capybara'                                # Switched from Webrat to Capybara w/ Rails 4.2
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.7.0'             # Added version when moving to Rails 4.0.13
  gem 'timecop'
end

gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'retina_tag'

gem 'useragent'
```

Comment: Two questions: which version of bundler are you running, and can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Bundler version 1.17.3

Comment: BTW, there may be problems with the Gemfile that I can resole by removing/changing versioning on some gems, but right now I'm focusing on the first error (because most all of the errors look like that, and if I'm reading the message correctly, it doesn't make sense ">= 3.0" and "= 5.0.6" should be compatible dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved this.

1. Remove versions from Gemfile for all gems (except Ruby and Rails).
2. Delete Gemfile.lock
3. Bundle install

In my case, I got a number of build errors on gems with native extensions. Most were related to a change to CLANG, the Mac OS X C compiler, requiring me to add `-- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"` to the gem install.